# Problem with articles feed: XML Parsing Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity

Tags: posts, rss, feed, seo, cms

I have a problem with WordPress articles feed. I have discover it analyzing what googlebot is scanning on my site and I disconvered that it is scanning only the feed and not the articles...

So I have try to open feeds URL scanned by Googlebot and I have found a bad surprise...if I try to open these links go into error...all times...

For example you can try to open this link and say the error:
http://www.scorejava.com/2013/04/09/27-aspect-orienting-programming-aop-in-spring/feed/

That in english sound like: **XML Parsing Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity**

I think that it is creating me big indexing problem !!!

Why have I this problem? How can I solve it?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 1):

You have rogue whitespace somewhere  - maybe in functions.php, maybe in wp-config.php, maybe elsewhere. This is a common problem. You need to locate and remove the whitespace.

Comment: now I will see if I have this withespace...the strange thing is that if I don't use permalink I can open the feeds url as this: www.scorejava.com/?p=5/feed and I have noe error